# jquery replacing one div with another

Tags: jquery

In the following, I want to remove class "item1" and add class item2 to maindiv. The code below is not working. What is wrong with the code and how do I include item2 in maindiv?

HTML:

```
<div class="item2"><a href="#" id="item2">item2</a></div>
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="item1"> <a href="#" id="item1">item1</a></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if (selection) {
    if ($('.maindiv').hasClass('item1')) {
        $('.maindiv').removeClass('item1').addClass('item2');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made a mistake pasting your code or is this how it actually looks?

Comment: Your question title doesn't really match up with what you've said in the question, and I'm not sure if that's just poor communication or confusion about what a class is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `.maindiv` doesn't have a class named `item1`, it has a 
*child*  that has that class. You're testing if *it* has it.

You may want to revise to something like:

```
if($('.maindiv > div').hasClass('item1')) {
    $('.maindiv > div')
        .removeClass('item1')
        .addClass('item2');
}
```

Or

```
if($('.maindiv .item1').length > 0) {
    $('.maindiv .item1')
        .removeClass('item1')
        .addClass('item2');
}
```

... whichever you find more readable.

Comment: This neither removes nor adds accordingly

Comment: @learning: I'm not sure I understand your objection. [Are both items blue in this example?](http://jsfiddle.net/YCqce/). Because if they are, you'll know that they have `item2` and not `item1`.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to target inner div like

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       if(selection) {
           $('.maindiv .item1').removeClass('item1').addClass('item2');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.hasClass()` function checks that the element(s) it's being called on have that class (in your case it doesn't). It does not check that those elements contain an element with that class.

`<div class="item1">` and `<div class="item2">` are *elements*, not classes; `item1` and `item2` are classes on those elements. You seem to be confused about what a class is and what the `.hasClass()`, `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` functions do, so I'd suggest you go back and cover the basics.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#maindiv').find('item1')` and than you can chain it.

Answer (score -1):

use id comparator for better solution like

item1

```
<div class = "maindiv"> 
<div id="test" class = "item1" >  <a href="#" id="item1">item1</a> </div>
</div>

if(selection)
            {             
                if ( $('#test').hasClass('item1') ) {
                            $('#test').removeClass('item1').addClass('item2');

                }


            }
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `.child()` function.

Comment: ohh thanks so you can use this using id its best way and accurate